# Is Ideal LPF BIBO unstable?

Tags: filters, linear-systems

In one of other discussions : [How to find frequency response, stability, and causality of a linear system?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/how-to-find-frequency-response-stability-and-causality-of-a-linear-system/1024)

I found a comment which was quite strong and definitely caught my attention.

> An ideal low-pass filter is an example of a system that is not BIBO
>   stable even though its frequency response is bounded for all $f$

I am following the definition of stability as per here in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability

Can anyone give me a proof that ideal LPF can indeed be BIBO unstable?

Of course, ideal LPF with *infinite* gain can produce unbounded output. The question is restricted to LPF when gain is finite.

Comment: An ideal LPF has impulse response of the form $h(t) =\text{sinc}(t)$ which does _not_ satisfy the condition $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt < \infty$ needed for BIBO stability.  Thus, the response at $t=0$ to the _bounded_ signal $x(t) = \text{sgn}(\text{sinc}(t))$ (which switches back and forth between $+1$ and $-1$) is $$\int h(-t)x(t)dt =  \int h(t)x(t)dt = \int |h(t)|dt = \infty$$ and so an ideal LPF is not a BIBO-stable system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is a response to a comment by the OP on on yoda's answer.

Suppose that $h(t)$, the impulse response of a continuous-time 
linear time-invariant system, has the property that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |h(t)| \mathrm dt = M$$ for
some finite number $M$.  Then, for **each and every** 
bounded input $x(t)$, the output $y(t)$ is bounded also.
If $|x(t)| \leq \hat{M}$ for all $t$ where $\hat{M}$
is some finite number, then $|y(t)| \leq \hat{M}M$ for all $t$
where $\hat{M}M$ is also a finite number.
The proof is straightforward.
$$\begin{align*}
|y(t)| &= \left |\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)x(t - \tau)\mathrm d\tau\right |\\
&\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(\tau)x(t - \tau)|\mathrm d\tau\\
&\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(\tau)|\cdot|x(t - \tau)|\mathrm d\tau\\
&\leq \hat{M}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(\tau)|\mathrm d\tau\\
&= \hat{M}M.
\end{align*}$$
In other words, $y(t)$ is bounded whenever $x(t)$ is bounded.

> Thus, the condition 
>   $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |h(t)| \mathrm dt < \infty$
>   is sufficient for BIBO-stability.
>
> The condition  $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |h(t)| \mathrm dt < \infty$
>   is also necessary for BIBO-stability.

Assume that *every* bounded input
produces a bounded output.  Now consider the input 
$x(t) = \text{sgn}(h(-t)) ~\forall~ t$.  This is clearly bounded,
($|x(t)| \leq 1$ for all $t$), and at $t=0$, it produces output
$$\begin{align*}
y(0) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(0-\tau)x(-\tau)\mathrm d\tau\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(-\tau)\text{sgn}(h(-\tau))\mathrm d\tau
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(-\tau)|\mathrm d\tau\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(t)|\mathrm dt.
\end{align*}$$
Our assumption that the system is BIBO stable means that $y(0)$ is 
necessarily finite, that is,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |h(t)| \mathrm dt < \infty$$

The proof for discrete-time systems is similar with the obvious 
change that all the integrals are replaced by sums.

Ideal LPFs are not BIBO-stable 
systems because the impulse response is not absolutely integrable,
as stated in the answer by yoda.  But his answer does not really answer the question

> Can anyone give me a proof that ideal LPF can indeed be BIBO unstable?

A specific example of a bounded input signal that produces an unbounded output
from an ideal LPF (and thus proves that the system is *not* BIBO-stable)
can be constructed as outlined above (see also my comment on the main question).

Answer (score 5):

A necessary condition for BIBO stability is the existence of the $L^1$ norm (or $\ell^1$ norm for discrete systems) of the impulse response. From the wiki article you cited,

> For a continuous time linear time invariant (LTI) system, the
>   condition for BIBO stability is that the impulse response be
>   absolutely integrable, i.e., its L1 norm exist.
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(t)|\ dt=\Vert h(t)\Vert_1<\infty$$

The impulse response of an ideal LPF is the $\text{sinc}$ function, which only has the $L^2$ norm and not the $L^1$ norm. In other words, $\text{sinc}(t)$ is **not** absolutely summable or

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\text{sinc}(t)|\ dt=\infty$$

Hence, an ideal LPF is not BIBO stable despite its frequency response being bounded for all $f$.

Comment: From what i thought *impulse response be absolutely summable, i.e., its L1 norm exist.* is a *sufficient condition* that a system is BIBO stable. However, is this a necessary condition that must hold?

Answer (score -2):

The fourier transform of ideal lpf is sinc function in time domain which exist from -infinite to +infinite so it is noncausal and area within it is infinite so unbounded. ..

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Thanks for your answer, but I do not think that it adds anything to the existing answers. Furthermore, it is not true that the area under the sinc function is unbounded, it is the area under the *magnitude* of the sinc function that is unbounded. The latter causes the system's instability.